# How to pass $_GET variables from a link to a bootstrapmodal?

Tags: php, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal

Snippet from my HTML code.

```
<td><span data-placement="top" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Show"><a href="#" class="btn btn-primary btn-xs" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#editBox" data-book-id="<?php echo $obj->id;?>"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></span></a></span></td>
```

The modual that are beeing opened when link is clicked:

```
<!-- Modal -->
    <div class="modal fade" id="editBox" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
      <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
          <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
            <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Modal title</h4>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-body">
            <?php var_dump($_GET)?>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Is there a proper way to pass my id into the modal?

Comment: with your approach it will not work but need bit more information, is the modal call button inside while loop?

Comment: Modual is outside a loop, but the id are passed from a  while.

Comment: and you are trying to fetch the data in module from database against the id?

Comment: when i click on the link, i have the unique id, i want to pass into the modual.

Comment: I get that you want to pass the id to module but what i was asking is the next step what will you do with the id if it passed to module, what you want to show in module with passed id?

Comment: i want to fetch data from a database, and make a editform.,

Comment: check the answer and lemme know if you have any question

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The simple solution to pass `id`, fetch records from database against passed `id` and show in modal is;

---

**Simple Solution**

Modal Call button

```
<td><span data-placement="top" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Show"><a class="btn btn-primary btn-xs" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#editBox" href="file.php?id=<?php echo $obj->id;?>"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></span></a></span></td>
```

Modal HTML

Put following modal HTML outside the `while loop` in page where the above call button is located (preferable at bottom of page)

```
<div class="modal fade" id="editBox" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
          //Content Will show Here
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Now Create a PHP file and name it `file.php`

This file is called with modal call button `href="file.php?id=<?php echo $obj->id;?>"`

```
<?php
//Include database connection here
$Id = $_GET["id"]; //escape the string if you like
// Run the Query
?>
<div class="modal-header">
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
    <h4 class="modal-title"><center>Heading</center></h4>
</div>
<div class="modal-body">
    //Show records fetched from database against $Id
</div>
<div class="modal-footer">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
</div>
```

To remove the data inside modal or in other words to refresh the modal when open next records without page refresh, use following script

Put it after jQuery and Bootstrap library (Remember jQuery & Bootstrap libraries always come first)

```
<script>
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $('#editBox').on('hidden.bs.modal', function () {
          $(this).removeData('bs.modal');
    });
});
</script>
```

---

**Alternate Solution with Ajax and Bootstrap Modal Event Listener**

In Modal Call button replace `href="file.php?id=<?php echo $obj->id;?>` with data attribute `data-id="<?php echo $obj->id;?>"` so we pass the id of row to modal using [bootstrap modal event](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals-events)

```
<td><span data-placement="top" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Show"><a class="btn btn-primary btn-xs" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#editBox" data-id="<?php echo $obj->id;?>"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></span></a></span></td>
```

Modal HTML

Put following modal HTML outside the `while loop` in page where the above call button is located (preferable at bottom of page)

```
<div class="modal fade" id="editBox" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                <h4 class="modal-title"><center>Heading</center></h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <div class="form-data"></div> //Here Will show the Data
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Now Add following script in same page;

```
<script>
//jQuery Library Comes First
//Bootstrap Library
$( document ).ready(function() {       
    $('#myModal').on('show.bs.modal', function (e) { //Modal Event
        var id = $(e.relatedTarget).data('id'); //Fetch id from modal trigger button
    $.ajax({
      type : 'post',
       url : 'file.php', //Here you will fetch records 
      data :  'post_id='+ id, //Pass $id
      success : function(data){
         $('.form-data').html(data);//Show fetched data from database
       }
    });
    });
});
</script>
```

Now Create a PHP file and name it `file.php` (same as use in Ajax Method)

```
<?php
//Include database connection here
if($_POST['id']) {
    $id = $_POST['id'];
    // Run the Query
    // Fetch Records
    // Echo the data you want to show in modal
 }
?>
```

In this solution, you don't need following script to remove the data inside modal or in other words to refresh the modal

```
$('#editBox').on('hidden.bs.modal', function () {
      $(this).removeData('bs.modal');
});
```

---

**Alternate Solution with Ajax and jQuery Click function**

Modal Call button

```
<td><span data-placement="top" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Show"><a class="btn btn-primary btn-xs" class="open-modal" href="" id="<?php echo $obj->id;?>"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></span></a></span></td>
```

Put following modal HTML in page where above modal call button located (preferable at bottom of page)

```
<div class="modal fade" id="editBox" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
                <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Modal title</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <div class="form-data"></div> //Here Will show the Data
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

following Ajax method code in same page where Modal HTML & Modal call button located.

```
<script>
//jQuery Library Comes First
//Bootstrap Library
$( document ).ready(function() { 
  $('.open-modal').click(function(){
    var id = $(this).attr('id');
    $.ajax({
      type : 'post',
       url : 'file.php', //Here you should run query to fetch records
      data : 'post_id='+ id, //Here pass id via 
      success : function(data){
          $('#editBox').show('show'); //Show Modal
          $('.form-data').html(data); //Show Data
       }
    });
  });
});
</script>
```

And the PHP file `file.php` will be same as the *above solution with bootstrap modal event*

---

**Pass On page information to Modal**

In some cases, only need to pass (display) minimal information to modal which already available on page, can be done with just bootstrap modal event without `Ajax Method` with `data-attributes`

```
<td>
  <span data-placement="top" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Show">
    <a data-book-id="<?php echo $obj->id;?>" data-name="<?php echo $obj->name;?>" data-email="<?php echo $obj->email;?>" class="btn btn-primary btn-xs" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#editBox">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></span>
    </a>
  </span>
</td>
```

Modal Event

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#editBox').on('show.bs.modal', function (e) {
        var bookid = $(e.relatedTarget).data('book-id');
        var name = $(e.relatedTarget).data('name');
        var email = $(e.relatedTarget).data('email');
        //Can pass as many onpage values or information to modal  
     });
});
```

Comment: Is there a way to skip the file.php? and exchange it with a php function?

Comment: as far my knowledge, no, you can't skip file.php, logical reason is that when page loads everything on it loads too and when you call modal with id, how you expect to run a function or query while staying on same page and without any external file source.

Comment: Im interested in your last example "Pass On page information to Modal". For the sake of argument, let's say `<a data-book-id="<?php echo $obj->id;?>"` is equal to `<a data-book-id="10"` ... how can I bring "10" into the modal window and assign it to a php variable? ie: `<?php $bookID = '10'; ?>` ?