# Dynamically load modal-dialog in one page

Tags: php, mysql, modal-dialog

I have a table in one page where each row refer to a modal dialog with form...
It's all loaded from mysql db with php

For example

```
SELECT id, name FROM db
While fecth() .... {
<tr>
  <td><button data-target="#modal_<?php echo $id; ?>">show first</button>
    <div id="modal_<?php echo $id; ?>">
      <form action ...>
         <input type="text" value="<?php echo $name; ?>">
         <input type="hidden" value"modal<?php echo $id; ?>">
         <input type="submit" value="submit">
      </form>
    </div>
  </td>
  <td><?php echo $name; ?></td>
</tr>
}
```

There can be lot of row in a table and this weighs the page... The source was very long

How can I write one modal dialog and then load based on ID ?

Comment: are you using `jQuery ui modal-dialog`?

Comment: yes... I'm developing from AdminLTE base code

Comment: I posted the solution as answer, see if it helps, any question, feel free to ask

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The very simple and straight solution is;

If you are using [jQuery UI Dialog](https://jqueryui.com/dialog/)

For Reference, the page name `index.php` and displaying fetched data from database (as stated in question)

1. Replace `data-target="#modal_<?php echo $id;?>"` with `class="open" id="<?php echo $id; ?>"`
2. bind `open` selector with [jQuery click function](https://api.jquery.com/click/)

   ```
   $(".openmodal").click(function();
   ```
3. create variable `id` and fetch `id="<?php echo $id; ?>"` from button attribute.

   ```
   var id = $(this).attr("id");
   ```
4. Use [Ajax Method](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) to fetch data against the `id` and show in modal

Modal open button will be

```
<tr>
  <td><button class="open" id="<?php echo $id; ?>">show first</button></td>
  <td><?php echo $name; ?></td>
</tr>
```

And Modal HTML will be

```
<div id="dialog" style="display:none;">
    <div id="Schedule"></div> //Here we show the content in Modal
</div>
```

and Ajax Method will be

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".openmodal").click(function() {
        var id = $(this).attr("id");
        alert(id);
        var dataString = 'id='+ id;
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "ajax.php",
                data: dataString,
                cache: false,
                success: function(data) {
                    $("#dialog").dialog();
                    $("#Schedule").html(data);
                } 
            });
        });
 });
```

Now create `ajax.php` to use in Ajax method;

```
<?php
//connection to the database
if($_POST['id']) {
    $id = $_POST['id'];
    //Run Query to fetch the data against `$id`
?>
 //This form with fetched detail from database will show in Modal
  <form action="" name="" class="" id="">
     <input type="text" value="<?php echo $variable; ?>">
     <input type="submit" value="submit">
  </form>
<?php } ?>
```

And if you are using [bootstrap modal](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals) you can check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32433765/how-to-pass-get-variables-from-a-link-to-a-bootstrapmodual/32434127#32434127).