# Passing selected GET value (example id) to Edit button in Bootstrap

Tags: php, pdo, modal-dialog

I have a list of records displayed. I used Edit and Delete button (modal). When I click the Edit button it should href to php file which accepts the GET value passed through Edit and display a modal which has values displayed from a mysql table for editing and updating. Using PDO which i am new to use.

```
<a href="modalstaffedit.php?edit_id=<?php $row['id']; ?>">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-xs" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModaledit">
        Edit
    </button>
</a>
```

It sends the id to a php file which extract the record from the table using PDO and the php file has code for modal and the modal should display the values of the table for editing. Its not working. Thanks for help.

Comment: Define *"Its not working"*. Rather a broad subject.

Comment: Sir I am new here. Any how I accept what your you tell to do thanks

Comment: Plus, you have given us one line of code. Put yourself in our shoes for a minute. What if we were to give you one line of code for a project you wanted to build. You'd ask us for the missing parts, right? Well there you go ;-)

Comment: @VenkatSuresh see if this answer helps you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32433765/how-to-pass-get-variables-from-a-link-to-a-bootstrapmodual/32434127#32434127

Answer (score 0):

Did you try echoing $row['id'] value

```
<a href="modalstaffedit.php?edit_id=<?php echo $row['id']; ?>" class="btn btn-info btn-xs" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModaledit">Edit</a>
```

Comment: Yes sir i did after reading a comment here I changed to                       <a class="btn btn-primary btn-xs" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModaledit" href="modalstaffedit.php?edit_id=<?php print($row['id'])?>"<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></span>Edit</a>  and the modal line displays but no window is shown with the id passed to edit

Comment: pls use echo instead of print pls so i can predict what is happening on your side. Can you explain me why you putting span inside a tag. pls. thanks @VenkatSuresh

Comment: Thanks Standej Sir I removed all those spans. I tried the one posted here. I changed to a new one as mentioned above. Now the value id is passed to the modalstaffedit.php I checked there. In that file I have BS modal code to open the modal as mentioned in data-target above. It shows a 1mm line of the modal. Then nothing.

Comment: @VenkatSuresh if the modal is showing (the 1mm line) nothing else, means your query is failing or something else is wrong in your PHP code, and as there is no PHP code in your original post so can't even guess

Comment: Thanks shehary sir But I checked the value of the id passed and the corresponding database values. Extracting fine But nothing in the modal. I have modal to display the values of the selected id to do editing option in the modal

Comment: and leaving everyone still guessing with one line of code. @VenkatSuresh

Comment: Sorry dear members. I am novice and in the learning process. I tried to display as shehary told to display the value of emailid using the id sent. Its extracting fine and I checked the value in the pdo class which extracts the record from database. I tried to echo the variable just above modal code and its not showing. I think the variable which stores the query content is not showing even though there is return steditr . How can I use the steditr[table field] in the modal file included below the pdo extract function. Thanks members you are all great.

Comment: <a class="btn btn-primary btn-xs" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Edit</a>                      This line calls a modal without issues.                                                                                                   <a class="btn btn-primary btn-xs" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal" href="modalstaff.php?edit_id=<?php echo ($row['id'])?>">Edit</a>  When i pass a value in href it does not open a modal where modal staff has code for modal