# Passing value to Bootstrap Modal for PHP PDO Query

Tags: php, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, pdo, bootstrap-modal

I am displaying a table of values with two options, delete or update. When I select delete I want to display the row to be deleted. This last point using Bootstrap Modals.

This is my Delete Modal

```
<div class="modal bounceIn animated" id="Delete" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
        <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Delete a Campaign</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body edit-content">

        <p>Please find the campaign ID to be deleted below</p>
        <input type="text" name="bookId" id="bookId" value="" />


        <table class='table table-bordered'>
          <tr>
            <th>#</th>
            <th>Description</th>
            <th>Creation Date</th>
            <th>Credit</th>
            <th>ROI</th>
            <th>Active</th>
          </tr>
          <?php

             $id = $row['data-campaignid'];// This is where I am having the problem
             $stmt = $user_home->runQuery("SELECT * FROM campaigns WHERE id_campaigns=:id");
               $stmt->execute(array(":id"=>$id));
             while($row=$stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_BOTH))
             {
                 ?>
            <tr>
              <th>
                <?php print($row['id_campaigns']); ?>
              </th>
              <th>
                <?php print($row['descripcion']); ?>
              </th>
              <th>
                <?php print($row['fec_creacion']); ?>
              </th>
              <th>
                <?php print($row['saldo']); ?>
              </th>
              <th>
                <?php print($row['ROI']); ?>
              </th>
              <th>
                <?php print($row['active']); ?>
              </th>
            </tr>
            <?php
             }
             ?>
        </table>

      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!-- modal-content -->
  </div>
  <!-- modal-dialog -->
</div>
<!-- end -->
```

So as you can see I am passing a value "bookid" to the modal using the following JQuery script

```
$(document).on("click", ".open-DeleteDialog", function () {
     var myCampaignId = $(this).data('campaignid');
     $(".modal-body #bookId").val( myCampaignId );

});
```

The difficulty I am encountering is how to use the value of the input (bookID) to pass it over to the PHP PDO Query and execute it while being able to show that data on the table.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to pass $\_GET variables from a link to a bootstrapmodual?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32433765/how-to-pass-get-variables-from-a-link-to-a-bootstrapmodual)

Answer (score 0):

JQuery is executed on client side while SQL queries are on server side.
So, you need to use AJAX. This would be a very long answer, please take a look at this [CRUD+AJAX tutorial](http://mbahcoding.com/php/codeigniter/codeigniter-ajax-crud-using-bootstrap-modals-and-datatable.html).