# Q: PHP Multiple Modal in a button of while loop

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

Hello guys can somebody help me I have a multiple button executes in while loop. I want to view a separate modal in each button.

Here's my button:

```
<a href="#myModalRemarks" class="remarksBtn" data-toggle="modal"><i class="fa fa-info-circle fa-lg"></i></a>
```

My button was inside the while loop because I want to fetch a data which is remarks and I want to view those multiple fetch data inside my modal.

```
<?php
    include('connection.php');

    $sql1 = "SELECT remarks FROM tbl_encode_transmittal WHERE receiver_id = '".$_SESSION['userid']."'";

    $rs1 = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());

    while($row1 = mysql_fetch_array($rs1)){?>
        <!-- Modal -->
        <div class="modal fade" id="myModalRemarks" role="dialog">
            <div class="modal-dialog">
                <!-- Modal content -->
                <div class="modal-content">
                    <div class="modal-header">
                        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                        <h4 class="modal-title">Remarks</h4>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-body">
                        <?php echo $row1['remarks']; ?>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-footer">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
           <?php } ?>
           </div>
        </div>
```

In modal id of my code I want to add number like this `<div class="modal fade" id="myModalRemarks1" role="dialog">` and everytime I fetch a multiple data the modal also have a increment number so that it will set a different id.

Comment: so what's the question? any errors, are you checking for them? did you check your console if you're using JS with this? did you start the session? Edit: Oh, this is a *"how-to"* question.

Comment: imagine you have 100 records and for each record you have one modal so for 100 records 100 modals, what will happen to the page load time?

Comment: your approach is wrong, should look at this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32433765/how-to-pass-get-variables-from-a-link-to-a-bootstrapmodal

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I urge you to look at this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32433765/how-to-pass-get-variables-from-a-link-to-a-bootstrapmodal) and follow the answer for better approach, as far your original approach in question

Modal button (which is inside the loop) add the row id `receiver_id` to modal button `href="#myModalRemarks<?php echo $row1['receiver_id'];?>"`

```
<a href="#myModalRemarks<?php echo $row1['receiver_id'];?>" class="remarksBtn" data-toggle="modal"><i class="fa fa-info-circle fa-lg"></i></a>
```

And Modal HTML (which is also inside the loop) add row id `receiver_id` to modal selector id `id="myModalRemarks<?php echo $row1['receiver_id'];?>"`

```
<div class="modal fade" id="myModalRemarks<?php echo $row1['receiver_id'];?>" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <!-- Modal content -->
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                <h4 class="modal-title">Remarks</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <?php echo $row1['remarks']; ?>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            </div>
        </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

and the modal will have unique id too

Comment: thank you very much your code it works.