# Charging information within the modal (bootstrap 3.3.6)?

Tags: php, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, modal-dialog, bootstrap-modal

I have a modal and after clicking on the **Visualizar** option I want it to load information from a `table`.

However, it only loads the first table ID, regardless of which item of the table I want to view. It always shows the same information.

Below is the code I'm using.

```
<div class="container-fluid">
<table class="table table-striped" data-toggle="table"
       data-search="true"
       data-show-refresh="true"
       data-show-columns="true">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th class="th-small" data-align="left" data-sortable="true">ID</th>
            <th data-align="left" data-sortable="true">Nome</th>
            <th class="th-small">Ações</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <?php
        foreach ($idade as $key => $v) {
            ?>
            <tr>

                <td><?= $v->id ?></td>
                <td><?= $v->titulo ?></td>
                <td>
                    <form data-toggle="validator" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                    <div class="dropdown">
                        <button class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" type="submit" data-toggle="dropdown">... <span class="caret"></span></button>
                        <ul class="table-modal dropdown-menu">
                            <li class=""><a data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modal-select">Visualizar</a></li>
                            <li><a data-toggle="modal" data-target="#editarIdade">Editar</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </td>
            </tr>
        <?php } ?>
    </tbody>
</table>

<!-- Modal VISUALIZAR -->
<div class="modal fade" id="modal-select" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
                <h4 class="modal-title" id="cadastroIdadelLabel">Visualizar - Idade</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <form class="form-inline" role="form" data-toggle="validator" action="Idade/page/visualizar">
                    <fieldset>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <div>
                                <label>Idade:</label>
                                <?= $v->titulo ?>

                            </div>
                            <div>
                                <label>Código:</label>
                                <?= $v->id ?>
                            </div>

                        </div>
                    </fieldset>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Voltar</button>

            </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Could anyone help me find the issue?

Comment: Where's the code that opens the modal and passes the data into to it? Btw, from what I can see you're hard coding the values in the modal  markup (echoing PHP-variables) so of course that info will be shown every time.

Answer (score 0):

First, you have open `<form>` tag inside `foreach` code (Sidenote: He doesn't need a form here)

```
<?php foreach ($idade as $key => $v) {?>
    <tr>
        <td><?= $v->id ?></td>
        <td><?= $v->titulo ?></td>
        <td>
            <form data-toggle="validator" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            <div class="dropdown">
                <button class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" type="submit" data-toggle="dropdown">... <span class="caret"></span></button>
                <ul class="table-modal dropdown-menu">
                    <li class=""><a data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modal-select">Visualizar</a></li>
                    <li><a data-toggle="modal" data-target="#editarIdade">Editar</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            </form>
        </td>
    </tr>
<?php } ?>
```

Second you have to put `<form>` tag before `modal-body` inside Modal (sidenote: `<?= $v->titulo ?>` and `<?= $v->id ?>` will not show any value outside `foreach`

```
<div class="modal fade" id="modal-select" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
                <h4 class="modal-title" id="cadastroIdadelLabel">Visualizar - Idade</h4>
            </div>
            <form class="form-inline" role="form" data-toggle="validator" action="Idade/page/visualizar">
            <div class="modal-body">
                    <fieldset>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <div>
                                <label>Idade:</label>
                                <?= $v->titulo ?>

                            </div>
                            <div>
                                <label>Código:</label>
                                <?= $v->id ?>
                            </div>

                        </div>
                    </fieldset>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Voltar</button>
            </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Third you have to add the id `<?= $v->id ?>` as data attribute `data-id="<?= $v->id ?>"` to modal trigger button and with BS Modal event, pass it to modal when modal shown

```
<li class=""><a data-id="<?= $v->id ?>" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modal-select">Visualizar</a></li>
```

Modal show event.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#modal-select').on('show.bs.modal', function (e) {
        var id = $(e.relatedTarget).data('id');
        alert(id);
        //pass `id` to input, HTML selector do what ever you like with it
     });
});
```

Fourth, To fetch data against `id` from database and show in modal, have a look at this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32433765/how-to-pass-get-variables-from-a-link-to-a-bootstrapmodal).

You can ask if needs more explanation or help with any step.