# Reusing Bootstrap Modal with Dynamic PHP Data

Tags: javascript, php, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal

I find modals challenging, and I am working on someone else's code with a new spin on modals that I really like (if I can just get it to work).

The modal is populated with item-specific information based on an ID, but when a user clicks to exit and selects the modal trigger for different item-specific information based on a unique ID- they get the old information. It almost seems like the modal needs to be destroyed in between triggers. Here is how it needs to work for this project:

1. Populate Inventory Page With Database Information
2. On Action Click, Take Item ID And Pass To Modal
3. Show Modal With More Item Specific Information
4. Allow Users To Close Modal And Click Another Item Action
5. Repeat steps 2-4

Here is my current code:

**inventory.php**

the trigger:

```
 <a data-toggle="modal" data-target="#ajax" data-id="<? echo $row['id'];?>" href="./mod/v_email.php?id=<? echo $row['id'];?>" class="btn red btn-sm dropdown-toggle inv_action">Email <i class="icon-note"></i></a>
```

then the modal initialization at the bottom of the page:

```
 <div class="modal fade" id="ajax" role="basic" aria-hidden="true">
     <div class="page-loading page-loading-boxed">
         <img src="../../assets/global/img/loading-spinner-grey.gif" alt="" class="loading">
         <span>
    &nbsp;&nbsp;Loading... </span>
     </div>
     <div class="modal-dialog">
         <div class="modal-content">
         </div>
     </div>
 </div>
```

**v_email.php**

```
 $id=($_GET['id']);

 <div class="modal-header">
    <button type="button" class="close" id="modal_close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true"></button>
    <h4 class="modal-title">Let someone know!</h4>
</div>
<div class="modal-body">
    <div class="row">
        <form id="veh_email_form" method="post">
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <div class="input-group">
                <span class="input-group-addon">
                    <i class="fa fa-user"></i>
                </span>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="name" placeholder="Name" required="required">
            </div>
            <div class="input-group">
                <span class="input-group-addon">
                    <i class="fa fa-envelope"></i>
                </span>
                <input type="email" class="form-control" name="email" placeholder="Email" required="required">
            </div>
            <div class="input-group">
                <textarea class="form-control" style="width:269px;height:117px;" rows="3" name="message" placeholder="Message">
                <? echo $id;?></textarea>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="modal-footer">
    <input type="submit" class="btn red-haze" value="Send Email">
</div>
</form>
<script src="../../assets/global/plugins/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){

        $("form#veh_email_form").on("submit",function() {
            $('form#veh_email_form input[type=submit]').attr({disabled: 'disabled',value: 'Submitting Application ...'});
            var formData = $("form#veh_email_form").serialize();
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: './mod/mod_helper/veh_email_proc.php',
                data: formData,
                async: false,
                success: function(msg){
                        if((msg) == 1)  {               
                            $("#modal_close").trigger("click");
                        } 
                        else { 
                            $("#app_error").show();
                        } 
                }               
            });             
            return false;               
        });
        $("#ajax").on('hidden.bs.modal', function () {
            $(this).data('bs.modal', null);
        });
        $("#modal_close").click(function() {
            $('#ajax').removeData('modal');
            }); 
    });
</script>
```

As you can see, I tried to delete/destroy the modal data both on click and on hide and neither work.

The current behavior:

Scenario 1:

- User clicks item 1- modal appears with item 1 data
- User closes item 1 modal
- User clicks item 2- modal appears with item 1 data

Scenario 2:

- User clicks item 3 - modal appears with item 3 data
- User closes item 3 modal
- User clicks item 1 - modal appears with item 3 data

What am I failing to see here, and please comment if you need more info- I can edit the question and add more (trying to include everything but also keep it small and readable)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest to Keep all the scripts in `inventory.php` page and remove from `v_email.php` page, it will resolve the problem when modal open with new item detail.

either you can use

```
$("#ajax").on('hidden.bs.modal', function () {
    $(this).data('bs.modal', null);
});
```

or

```
$("#ajax").on('hidden.bs.modal', function () {
    $(this).removeData('bs.modal');
});
```

to clear the old data from modal

**inventory.php**

HTML

```
<a data-toggle="modal" data-target="#ajax" data-id="<? echo $row['id'];?>" href="./mod/v_email.php?id=<? echo $row['id'];?>" class="btn red btn-sm dropdown-toggle inv_action">Email <i class="icon-note"></i></a>
 <div class="modal fade" id="ajax" role="basic" aria-hidden="true">
     <div class="page-loading page-loading-boxed">
         <img src="../../assets/global/img/loading-spinner-grey.gif" alt="" class="loading">
         <span>
    &nbsp;&nbsp;Loading... </span>
     </div>
     <div class="modal-dialog">
         <div class="modal-content">
         </div>
     </div>
 </div>
```

JS

Note: Put following code after jQuery and Bootstrap library (Remember jQuery & Bootstrap libraries always come first)

Replace `$("form#veh_email_form").on("submit",function()` with `$(document).on("submit", "#veh_email_form", function ()`

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $(document).on("submit", "#veh_email_form", function () {
            $('form#veh_email_form input[type=submit]').attr({disabled: 'disabled',value: 'Submitting Application ...'});
            var formData = $("form#veh_email_form").serialize();
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: './mod/mod_helper/veh_email_proc.php',
                data: formData,
                async: false,
                success: function(msg){
                        if((msg) == 1)  {               
                            $("#modal_close").trigger("click");
                        } 
                        else { 
                            $("#app_error").show();
                        } 
                }               
            });             
            return false;               
        });
        $("#ajax").on('hidden.bs.modal', function () {
            $(this).data('bs.modal', null);
        });
        $("#modal_close").click(function() {
            $('#ajax').removeData('modal');
        }); 
    });
</script>
```

**v_email.php**

```
<?php
 $id=($_GET['id']);
?>
 <div class="modal-header">
    <button type="button" class="close" id="modal_close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true"></button>
    <h4 class="modal-title">Let someone know!</h4>
</div>
<form id="veh_email_form" method="post">
<div class="modal-body">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <div class="input-group">
                <span class="input-group-addon">
                    <i class="fa fa-user"></i>
                </span>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="name" placeholder="Name" required="required">
            </div>
            <div class="input-group">
                <span class="input-group-addon">
                    <i class="fa fa-envelope"></i>
                </span>
                <input type="email" class="form-control" name="email" placeholder="Email" required="required">
            </div>
            <div class="input-group">
                <textarea class="form-control" style="width:269px;height:117px;" rows="3" name="message" placeholder="Message">
                <? echo $id;?></textarea>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="modal-footer">
    <input type="submit" class="btn red-haze" value="Send Email">
</div>
</form>
```

Comment: Not only does the new PHP still not show, but the form doesn't clear out either. After making these changes I still see the exact same behavior. There arent any errors in the console and the modals are dismissed correctly... but the data is still the same.

Comment: remove curly brackets `($_GET['id']);` to `$_GET['id'];`

Comment: still same behavior. It works the first time, but then after the first time it is still using the same data and variables so its almost like its not dumping it and creating a new one- its just hiding and redisplaying the old

Comment: suggest to look at this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32433765/how-to-pass-get-variables-from-a-link-to-a-bootstrapmodal, all possible methods to show data in modal. highly suggest 2nd solution, with minor changes it possible and will resolve the repeating data issue in modal