# Pass database PHP variable in a link to open the specific details from database in bootstrap MODAL

Tags: php, database, variables, modal-dialog

```
/* When this link is clicked, the bootstrap modal should open with the particular detail from database.*/


<?php

    $con = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "","tpevent");

    if(!isset($con))
    {
        die("Database Not Found");
    }
                   $schkt1= mysqli_query($con, "select * from t_tevent");

                    echo" <table>
                            <thead>
                              <tr>

                                <th>Title</th>
                                <th>Date</th>
                                <th>Venue</th>
                                <th>Uploaded On</th>
                              </tr>
                            </thead>
                        <tbody>";

                  while($stevt = mysqli_fetch_array($schkt1))
                        {


                           echo "<tr>";

                            echo "<td> <a style='cursor:pointer; text-decoration: none;' 
                                data-toggle='modal' data-target='#thisdiv'> <strong>" . $stevt[1] ."</strong></a></td>";


                           echo "<td>". $stevt[3] ."</td>";
                           echo "<td>" . $stevt[2] ."</td>";
                           echo "<td>" . $stevt[5] ."</td>";


                        ?>

                        <?php   
                           echo "</tr> ";
                        }

                 }  
              echo "</tbody>
           </table>";
             ?>




// my bootstrap modal :-


<div id="thisdiv" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
                <div class="modal-dialog">

                  <!-- Modal content-->
                  <div class="modal-content">
                        <div class="modal-header">
                            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>

                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-sm-12">
                                    <?php
                                        $trdet= mysqli_query($con, "select * from t_tevent where e_id= 'EVT0005'");
                                        while($tdet = mysqli_fetch_array($trdet))              
                                         {
                                     ?>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <h4 class="modal-title"><?php echo $tdet[1];  ?></h4>

                        </div>

                        <div class="modal-body">

                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-sm-6">
                                    <font style="color: #999999 ;  font-family:Verdana; font-weight: bold;">
                                        <strong>Venue:  </strong> 
                                    </font>

                                    <font style="  font-family:Verdana; font-weight: normal;">
                                            <?php echo $tdet[2];?>
                                    </font>
                                </div>

                                <div class="col-sm-6">     
                                    <font style="color: #999999 ;  font-family:Verdana; font-weight: bold;">
                                        <strong>Date:  </strong> 
                                    </font>

                                    <font style=" font-family:Verdana; font-weight: normal;">
                                            <?php echo $tdet[3];?>
                                    </font>

                              </div>
                            </div>

                             <div class="row" style="margin-top:14px;">
                                   <div class="col-sm-12">
                                       <font style="color: #999999 ;  font-family:Verdana; font-weight: bold;">
                                           <strong>Details:  </strong>
                                       </font>

                                       <p style="color: black;font-family:Verdana; font-weight: normal;margin-top:4px;margin-left:14px;">
                                               <?php echo $tdet[4];?>
                                       </p>
                                   </div>
                            </div>


                            <div class="row">
                               <div class="col-sm-12">
                                   <font style="color: #999999 ;  font-family:Verdana; font-weight: bold">
                                       <strong>Uploaded By </strong>
                                   </font>

                                   <font style="  font-family:Verdana; font-weight: normal;">
                                      <?php 
                                           $ctdname = mysqli_query($con, "select f_name from t_faculty where f_email='" . $tdet[6] ."'");
                                           $ctname = mysqli_fetch_assoc($ctdname);
                                           $ctshow    = $ctname["f_name"];

                                           echo $ctshow ;

                                       ?>
                                   </font>

                                   <font style="color: #999999 ;  font-family:Verdana; font-weight: bold">
                                       <strong>On </strong>
                                   </font>     

                                   <font style="font-family:Verdana; font-weight: normal;">
                                       <?php echo $tdet[5];  
                                           } 
                                       ?>
                                   </font>
                               </div>
                           </div>

                        </div>

                        <div class="modal-footer">

                              <input type="submit" name="stpart" value="Participate" style="margin-left: 100px;">   

                        </div>
                   </div>

                </div>
              </div>
```

Comment: Please help me soon !

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to pass $\_GET variables from a link to a bootstrapmodal?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32433765/how-to-pass-get-variables-from-a-link-to-a-bootstrapmodal)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get specific values in a modal or a page based on values you pass in the url then you have to set the variable in the ahref tag which leads to this page

You have to export the table rows dynamically with the url that will fetch the id that will pass through data to next page

```
//I have defined the primary key column name as uid to fetch data
$sql="SELECT * from table;"
$result="$conn->query($sql)";
while{
$row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result) ;
echo'<tr>
     <td>'.$row['columname'].''</td>
     <td> <a href="www.mysite.com/mypage.html?id=".$row['uid'].">EDIT</a></td>
     </tr>'
}
```

Now on the second page where you want data selected

```
if isset($GET_['id']){
$id="$GET_['id']";
//The select function
$sql="SELECT * from WHERE id=$id";
$result= $conn->query($sql);
while{$row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)}
//write the html that you want generated with dynamic values
echo'<tr><td>'.$row['name'].'</td><td>'.$row['gender'].'</td></tr>'
}
```

I hope this helps you you can feel free to write to me anish.thuruthiyath(at)outlook(dot)com