# passing selected datarow into modal bootstrap

Tags: javascript, php, modal-dialog, bootstrap-modal

I have a table which has a button in each row to show details of each record. what I need is to pass selected data row to modal.

here is my PHP code for display data

```
                <?php 
                include 'koneksi.php';

                $sql = "SELECT UPPER(id_site) AS id_site, UCASE(name_site) AS name_site, witel, UPPER(uplink) AS uplink, port_uplink, ip_uplink, UPPER(olt) AS olt, ip_olt, port_olt, ip_ont FROM data_site ORDER BY witel ASC";
                $result = $conn->query($sql);
                if($result->num_rows > 0){
                    //output data 
                    while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {             
                    echo "<tr>
                            <td>$row[id_site]</td>
                            <td>$row[name_site]</td>
                            <td>$row[witel]</td>
                            <td>$row[olt]</td>
                            <td>$row[ip_olt]</td>
                            <td>$row[port_olt]</td>
                            <td>$row[ip_ont]</td>
                            <td><button type='button' data-id='".$row['id_site']."' class='btn btn-xs btn-success' data-toggle='modal' data-target='#detail'>DETAIL</button></td>
                        </tr>";
                    }
                }
             ?>
```

this one for display data in modal

```
<?php 
                include 'koneksi.php';
                $sql = "SELECT * FROM data_site WHERE id_site = '".$row['id_site']."'";
                $result = $conn->query($sql);
                if($result->num_rows > 0){
                    while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
                        echo "<table>
                                <tr>
                                <td>ID Site </td>
                                <td>: $row[id_site]</td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                <td>Nama Site </td>
                                <td>: $row[name_site]</td>
                                </tr>                                   
                                <tr>
                                <td>Witel</td>
                                <td>: $row[witel]</td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                <td>OLT Hostname  </td>
                                <td>: $row[olt]</td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                <td>IP OLT </td>
                                <td>: $row[ip_olt]</td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                <td>Port OLT</td>
                                <td>: $row[port_olt]</td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                <td>IP ONT</td>
                                <td>: $row[ip_ont]</td>
                                </tr>
                            </table>
                        ";
                    }
                }
              ?>
```

and this is my modal

```
<div id="detail" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
          <div class="modal-dialog">

            <!-- Modal content-->
            <div class="modal-content">
              <div class="modal-header">
                <h4 class="modal-title"></h4>
              </div>
              <div class="modal-body">

              </div>
              <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
              </div>
            </div>

          </div>
        </div>
```

and my javascript

```
<script>
        $('#detail').on('show.bs.modal', function (e) {
            var uniqueId = $(e.relatedTarget).data('id');
            $('.modal-title').html('Detail site ' + uniqueId);
            $('.modal-body').html(uniqueId);
        });
</script>
```

Comment: first, make the JS script DOM ready

Comment: do you want to pass the onpage information to modal or you want to fetch the information against `$row['id_site']` from database and then show it in the modal?

Comment: i don't know what the different, but i think fetch the information.
can you give the link where i can learn JS?sorry, this code stuff really new to me.

Comment: posted a solution, also you can check this answer for more details and alternate ways http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32433765/how-to-pass-get-variables-from-a-link-to-a-bootstrapmodal

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need is an Ajax call inside `$('#detail').on('show.bs.modal', function (e) { }` to fetch data against `$row['id_site']`

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#detail').on('show.bs.modal', function (e) {
            var uniqueId = $(e.relatedTarget).data('id');
            //Ajax Method
            $.ajax({
                type : 'post',
                url : 'file.php', //Here you will fetch records 
                data :  'uniqueId='+ uniqueId, //Pass uniqueId
                success : function(response){
                    $('.modal-title').html('Detail site ' + uniqueId);
                    $('.modal-body').html(response);
                }
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

file.php

```
<?php 
include 'koneksi.php';
if($_POST['uniqueId']) {
    $uniqueId = $_POST['uniqueId']; //escape the string
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM data_site WHERE id_site = '".$uniqueId."'";
    $result = $conn->query($sql);
    if($result->num_rows > 0){
    while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        echo "<table>
                <tr>
                <td>ID Site </td>
                <td>: $row[id_site]</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                <td>Nama Site </td>
                <td>: $row[name_site]</td>
                </tr>                                   
                <tr>
                <td>Witel</td>
                <td>: $row[witel]</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                <td>OLT Hostname  </td>
                <td>: $row[olt]</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                <td>IP OLT </td>
                <td>: $row[ip_olt]</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                <td>Port OLT</td>
                <td>: $row[port_olt]</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                <td>IP ONT</td>
                <td>: $row[ip_ont]</td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        ";
    }
}
}
?>
```

Comment: Thanks for you answer @Shehary, i really appreciate, i think i'm start to understand how it work. But can you help me one more, in the modal there is an error said undefined uniqueId,, how do i fix it?

Comment: have a typo mistake `id_site = '".uniqueId."'"` in answer here `$sql = "SELECT * FROM data_site WHERE id_site = '".uniqueId."'";` fix it in code `$sql = "SELECT * FROM data_site WHERE id_site = '".$uniqueId."'";`

Comment: The Steps are simple, suppose you have 3 files `index.php` `koneksi.php` and `file.php`, all files located at same path, `index.php` has the JS script, and the table row from where you are triggering modal and modal HTML, `koneksi.php` i suppose has the database connection which includes in both `index.php` and `file.php` and last the `file.php` file has the code which posted above in answer, so when modal triggers and show, it makes ajax request and fetch data from `file.php` against `uniqueId` and show in modal

Comment: haa, i see, this work like charm, thanks a lot Shehary, it seems like i have a lot of thing to study, :D

Comment: Shehary sorry to bother you again, I am stuck again when I want to fetching data to another modal with different content.
So when I open modal Details, there is a Edit Button in that modal, I've try to send same ajax request. I copied your code to fetching data and change this line 

    $('#detail').on('show.bs.modal', function (e) {
to
    $('#edit').on('show.bs.modal', function (e) {

and

    url : 'modalb.php', to `url : 'edit.php',`

result when i click Edit button it display nothing, i've search and try many way which i thought can be the way. But nothing. the last way i try is this

Comment: things need to check browser console log for error if nothing there then the modal `#edit'` trigger button has `data-id` and if yes, does it contain values? if all good then check the PHP file, the variables names you are posting via ajax and receiving in php file are same?

Comment: by the way, stacked bootstrap modal is bad idea, bootstrap doesn't support stacked modal, you may face problem like modal backdrop overlapping or modal go behind backdrop, suggestion is when you open 2nd modal close first modal, can be done via javascript inside 2nd modal event

Comment: ya, the variables names are same, is that problem?
there is `data-dismiss="modal"` in Edit butn, which close the first modal and `data-target="#edit"` to launch second modal, is that proper way?

Comment: no that's not a problem, does it also has the data-id="value" data attribute and does it contain the value

Comment: no it doesn't, just `data-id="edit"`. I'm sorry if i'm misunderstading your question.

Comment: here you go, https://jsfiddle.net/g2uqjw9s/1/ if you need further help or need any explanation, ping me here, happy coding

Comment: wow, thank a lot again Shehary for great and clear explaination. :D

Comment: you are welcome and remove this `alert(editidId);` or change it to `alert(editId);` to see the id in alert when edit modal shown

Comment: First try, the function is running well, but in second try when I click the edit-btn via first modal, it's shown the first clicked data. It's need to be refresh first to get same data like in first modal. how I can fix them?and Shehary, would you make pseudocode for ajax script which you make for me? It's make me understand faster and more clear if I understand how to make it. Sorry for ask you something like this. I hope you don't mind. :D

Comment: then better solution will be create global variable and use it through out all the ajax calls, i made changes here https://jsfiddle.net/g2uqjw9s/3/ with comments and follow the changes. Note: make sure the global variable remain unique

Comment: Your explanation more than I expect, more clear and easy to understand. I'm noted it as basic for me to learn more, and your code running exactly what I want. So, thank again for your help and explanation Shehary, thank you very much. :D

Comment: you are most welcome, my guess is that you don't need `$('#edit').on('show.bs.modal', function(e) { });` at all, with current code structure, as soon the 2nd modal show it will execute the edit Ajax method and update the record, i think it will be better if you replace `$('#edit').on('show.bs.modal', function(e) { });` with on document click function bind with `save changes` button in 2nd modal

Comment: OR other way around is that change the `$('#edit').on('show.bs.modal', function(e) { });` with hide event ``$('#edit').on('hide.bs.modal', function() { });`` so when click on `save changes` it will close the modal and then the edit record ajax method execute but that's also not very good practice because in 2nd modal close button will also execute the ajax method on modal close so highly suggest to use click function so edit record ajax method only execute then `Save Changes` button clicked