# Auto populate data to a modal content from selected datatable row

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, laravel, bootstrap-modal

I have a tasks list in my view which is rendered using Datatables with edit button on each record that is linked opening the modal. What I want to do is whenever I click the button on a record in the datatable rows then when my modal appear the data from that row should be populated in my modal.

My modal will serve as an edit record. This is my code so far:

View:

```
<div class="wrapper wrapper-content animated fadeInRight">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-12">
                    <div class="ibox float-e-margins">
                        <div class="ibox-title">
                            <h5>My Tasks</small></h5>
                            <div class="ibox-tools">

                                <a class="collapse-link">
                                    <i class="fa fa-chevron-up"></i>
                                </a>


                                <a class="close-link">
                                    <i class="fa fa-times"></i>
                                </a>

                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <!-- Modal -->
                        <div id="myModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
                          <div class="modal-dialog">
                            <!-- Modal content-->
                            <div class="modal-content">
                              <div class="modal-header">
                                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                                <h4 class="modal-title">My Task</h4>
                              </div>
                              <div class="modal-body">
                                <p>Some text in the modal.</p>
                              </div>
                              <div class="modal-footer">
                                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                              </div>
                            </div>

                          </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="ibox-content">
                            <table id="MyTasks" class="table table-striped table-bordered" cellspacing="0" width="100%">

                                <thead>
                                    <tr>
                                        <th>ID</th>
                                        <th>Description</th>
                                        <th>Start</th>
                                        <th>End</th>
                                        <th>Added By</th>
                                        <th>Date Created</th>
                                        <th>Status</th>
                                        <th>Action</th>
                                    </tr>
                                </thead>

                                <tbody>
                                </tbody>
                            </table>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
@endsection
@section('tasks-index')
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#MyTasks').DataTable({
        processing: true,
        serverSide: true,
        ajax: 'tasks-list',
        columns: [
            {data: 'id', name: 'tasks.id'},
            {data: 'task_description', name: 'tasks.task_description'},
            {data: 'start_timestamp', name: 'tasks.start_timestamp'},
            {data: 'end_timestamp', name: 'tasks.end_timestamp'},
            {data: 'name', name: 'users.name'},
            {data: 'created_at', name: 'tasks.created_at'},
            {data: 'status', name: 'tasks.status'},
            {data: 'action', name: 'action'}
        ]
    });

}); 
</script>           
@endsection
```

Controller:

```
public function getTasksList()
{
  if(Auth::check() && Auth::user()->access_level == 1)
  {
    $tasks = Task::join('users', 'tasks.added_by', '=', 'users.id')
        ->select([
          'tasks.id',
          'tasks.task_description',
          'tasks.start_timestamp',
          'tasks.end_timestamp',
          'tasks.status',
          'users.name'
          ]);
  }
  else
  {
    $tasks = Task::join('users', 'tasks.added_by', '=', 'users.id')
        ->select([
          'tasks.id',
          'tasks.task_description',
          'tasks.start_timestamp',
          'tasks.end_timestamp',
          'tasks.status',
          'users.name',
          'tasks.created_at'
          ])->where('tasks.assigned_to', '=', Auth::user()->id);
  }

   return Datatables::of($tasks)
   ->addColumn('action', function ($tasks) {
            return '<a href="#" class="btn btn-xs btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit" data-href="tasks/'.$tasks->id.'"></i> Edit</a>';
        })->make(true);     
}
```

I know that I have to somehow pass the Task ID to the modal and make an ajax to query the data? but I am confuse how to do that.

Comment: Could You paste here your routing for this action? I mean `Route::get()`

Comment: Route::resource('tasks', 'TaskController');

Route::get('tasks-list', 'TaskController@getTasksList');

Comment: `Datatables::of($tasks)` is it a laravel bundle and which?

Comment: Froom here: http://datatables.yajrabox.com/

Comment: No worries. Already found a similar one. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35902444/passing-selected-datarow-into-modal-bootstrap. Problem fixed.