# passing data into modal with ajax in codeigniter

Tags: javascript, ajax, codeigniter, modal-dialog, bootstrap-modal

This is embarrassing, I once asked about this few months ago. Now I ask again because I'm failed to implementing this with codeigniter.

[my old question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35902444/passing-selected-datarow-into-modal-bootstrap?noredirect=1#comment59465963_35902444)

So, I want to update selected data via modal bootstrap. But first the selected data must passing into modal bootstrap by id which i stuck there.

**UPDATE**

I fixed my (terrible) code which is better than before, but still I need some help,

my view

```
<tbody id="showdata">
        <?php foreach ($fo as $f) { ?>
            <tr>
                <td><?php echo $f->siteid ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $f->sitename ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $f->witel ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $f->addr ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $f->lat ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $f->longi ?></td>
                <td><a href="javascript:;" class="btn btn-info item-detail" data="<?php echo $f->siteid ?>">Details</a></td>
            </tr>
<?php } ?>
```

this is my js function

```
$('#showdata').on('click', '.item-detail', function(){
    var siteid = $(this).attr('data');
    $('#myModal').modal('show');
    $('#home').find('h3').text('Data Teknisi');

    $.ajax({
        type: 'ajax',
        method: 'get',
        url: '<?php echo base_url() ?>admin/getById',
        data: {siteid: siteid},
        async: false,
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(data){
            $('input[name=siteid]').val(data.siteid);
            $('input[name=sitename]').val(data.sitename);
        },
        error: function(){
            alert('Could not displaying data');
        }           
    });
});
```

my controller

```
 function getById(){
    $result = $this->artikel->getById();
    echo json_encode($result);
}
```

my model

```
 public function getById(){
    $siteid = $this->input->get('siteid');
    $this->db->where('siteid', $siteid);
    $query = $this->db->get('datek');
    if($query->num_rows() > 0){
        return $query->row();
    }else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

I got some errors in console browser
"http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.3.js Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)send @ jquery-1.12.3.js:10261",

or this one
"jquery-1.12.3.js:10261 GET http://localhost/ci/admin/getById?siteid=BPP194 404 (Not Found)send @ jquery-1.12.3.js:10261ajax @ jquery-1.12.3.js:9750(anonymous function) @ admin:576dispatch @ jquery-1.12.3.js:5226elemData.handle @ jquery-1.12.3.js:4878"

Comment: you are sending the data to controller but not accepting there. You need to modify your controller to accept get parameters. Also you need to send the ```$id``` to model from your controller. If still the error then please update the question with error.

Comment: My answer was wrong, but  comment above adds something, You don;t pass $id to model function inside controller.

Comment: Undefined variable: datek. is an error in your MYSQL query

Comment: $id = $this->input->get('uniqueId'); $data['datek']  =   $this->artikel->get_by_id($id)->result();  What do you see? Or $this->input->post('uniqueId') if unique id is a post param.

Answer (score 1):

I'am sorry guys, it was my mistakes,
I forgot to change base url in config.php

Thanks for your comments.