# ADD using Bootstrap Modal form is not working

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, bootstrap-modal

I want to use a modal form to populate my current table but it won't work. I just need some help, I might have missed something here. Thanks!

Here's my code for the button:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#addModal" href="add_dept.php">+ Add Department</button>
```

Here's my code in the bottom of my file to show the modal content:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="addModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
<div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
    </div>
</div>
```

Here's my code for add_dept.php:

```
<?php include("../includes/config.php");
$reqErr = "";
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == "POST") {
  if(!empty($_POST['dept_name']) && !empty($_POST['dept_code'])) {
    $dept_name = $_POST['dept_name'];
    $dept_code = $_POST['dept_code'];
    $query_addDept = "INSERT INTO department(dept_name,dept_code) VALUES('$dept_name','$dept_code')";
    if(mysqli_query($con,$query_addDept)) {
        $reqErr = '<div class="alert alert-success" id="myAlert">
              <a href="" class="close"> &nbsp;  <i class="fa fa-times"></i></a>
            <i class="fa fa-check-circle"></i> Department added</div>';
            mysqli_close($con);
    }
    else {
      $reqErr = '<div class="alert alert-danger" id="myAlert">
            <a href="" class="close"> &nbsp;  <i class="fa fa-times"></i></a>
          <i class="fa fa-exclamation-circle"></i> Failed to add Department</div>';
    }
  }
}
?>

<?php echo $reqErr; ?>
<div class="modal-header">
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
    <h4 class="modal-title">Add Department</h4>
</div>
<div class="modal-body">
  <form method="POST" class="form" id="add-department" role="form">
  <div class="form-group">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="dept_name" name="dept_name" placeholder="Department Name" />
    <span class="help-block"></span>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="dept_code" name="dept_code" placeholder="Department Code" />
    <span class="help-block"></span>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-footer">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
    <input type="submit" id="submit_btn" class="btn btn-primary" />
  </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: check this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32433765/how-to-pass-get-variables-from-a-link-to-a-bootstrapmodal to fetch id from database, pass it to modal and update the record against it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#addModal" href="add_dept.php">+ Add Department</button>
```

delete the href=""

```
 <div class="modal fade" id="addModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
     <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
         <div class="modal-content">
              <?php require_once('add_dept.php'); ?>
         </div>
     </div>
</div>
```

add the last - close div

Comment: It worked! Thanks. Since I can't use href and data-target together in the button. How will I forward the row ID to the modal if I want to update the row? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

```
data-target="#addModal" href="add_dept.php"
```

Your problem is here.

You can't set your button as model trigger and as link to your create page.

You can trigger the modal and after another click on the modal, redirect to your add_dept.php page, or just redirect on click, without usng the modal.