# Jquery passing data attributes to modal on click link

Tags: jquery, bootstrap-modal

I am trying to pass some custom data attributes to a modal which is opened through a link .

The HTML snippet is as following:

```
<div class="btn-group">
 <button aria-expanded="false" class="btn btn-xs green dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" id="button_action" type="button">Action <i class="fa fa-angle-down"></i></button>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
     <li>
         <a id="modal_contact" data-userName="User1" data-toggle="modal" href="#option_contact">
         <i class="fa fa-check-square-o"></i> Contact</a>
     </li>
</ul>
</div>
```

The modal snippet is as following :

```
<div class="modal fade" data-backdrop="static" data-keyboard="false" id="option_contact" tabindex="-1">
 <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
            <button aria-hidden="true" class="close" data-dismiss="modal"
            type="button"></button>
            <h4 class="modal-title"></h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
        </div>
    </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

I seem to be unable to set "**modal-title**" with the value of attribute "**data-userName**".

The jquery  I thought would do so (only inserted alert to see if value is passed or not) :

```
$('#modal_contact').on('click', function() {
  var $el = $(this);
  var $username = $el.data('userName');
    alert(username);
  });
```

But it does not seem to work. What would be the proper approach to this ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to pass $\_GET variables from a link to a bootstrapmodal?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32433765/how-to-pass-get-variables-from-a-link-to-a-bootstrapmodal)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Try using bootstrap modal's event callbacks instead of click handler:

```
$('#option_contact').on('shown.bs.modal', function() {
  var $el = $("#modal_contact");
  var $username = $el.data('userName');
  alert(username);
});
```

Answer (score 2):

In order to set data dont use camelCase notation. Insted  use something like this `data-user_name="User1"`

```js
$('#modal_contact').on('click', function() {
  var $el = $(this);
  var $username = $(this).data('user_name');
    alert($username);
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="btn-group">
 <button aria-expanded="false" class="btn btn-xs green dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" id="button_action" type="button">Action <i class="fa fa-angle-down"></i></button>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
     <li>
         <a id="modal_contact" data-user_name="User1" data-toggle="modal" href="#option_contact">
         <i class="fa fa-check-square-o"></i> Contact</a>
     </li>
</ul>
</div>


<div class="modal fade" data-backdrop="static" data-keyboard="false" id="option_contact" tabindex="-1">
 <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
            <button aria-hidden="true" class="close" data-dismiss="modal"
            type="button"></button>
            <h4 class="modal-title"></h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
        </div>
    </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

**NOTE**

The data-* attributes consist of two parts:

1. The attribute name should not contain any uppercase letters, and must be at least one character long after the prefix "data-"
2. The attribute value can be any string

Answer (score 1):

Please check below snippet. you will find the username correctly. In your code you have mentioned "userName" to fetch the attribute value which should be "username".

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#modal_contact').on('click', function() {
    var $el = $(this);
    var $username = $el.data('username');
    alert($username);
    $(".modal-title").html($username);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="btn-group">
 <button aria-expanded="false" class="btn btn-xs green dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" id="button_action" type="button">Action <i class="fa fa-angle-down"></i></button>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
    <li>
      <a id="modal_contact" data-userName="User1" data-toggle="modal" href="#option_contact">
        <i class="fa fa-check-square-o"></i> Contact</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>

<div class="modal fade" data-backdrop="static" data-keyboard="false" id="option_contact" tabindex="-1">
 <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
            <button aria-hidden="true" class="close" data-dismiss="modal"
            type="button"></button>
            <h4 class="modal-title"></h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
        </div>
    </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is the preview [code solution](https://plnkr.co/edit/fmwzmlZ1Gjktg00l4DcL?p=preview)

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <script data-require="jquery@2.2.0" data-semver="2.2.0" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script data-require="bootstrap.js@*" data-semver="3.3.6" src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <link data-require="bootstrap-css@3.3.6" data-semver="3.3.6" rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.css" />
  <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
      $('#modal_contact').on('click', function() {

        var userName = $(this).attr("data-userName");
        $('.modal-title').append(userName);

      });
    });
  </script>
</head>

<body>


  <div class="btn-group">
    <button aria-expanded="false" class="btn btn-xs green dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" id="button_action" type="button">Action <i class="fa fa-angle-down"></i></button>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
      <li>
        <a id="modal_contact" data-userName="User1" data-toggle="modal" href="#option_contact">
          <i class="fa fa-check-square-o"></i> Contact</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="modal fade" data-backdrop="static" data-keyboard="false" id="option_contact" tabindex="-1">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <button aria-hidden="true" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" type="button"></button>
          <h4 class="modal-title"></h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```