# Bootstrap modal delete confirmation

Tags: php, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal

Good day! I've got a problem in my bootstrap modal where I want to delete a post using a modal.

Here is my PHP code where it toggles the delete_modal.php

```
<?php
    if ($row['member_id'] == $_SESSION['member_id']){
    echo " 
     <div style='float:right;'>
       <a href='#<?php echo $id; ?>' data-toggle='modal' data-target='#myModal'>Delete</a>
     </div>";}

    else{
    echo "
      <div style='float:right;'>
        <a href='#'>Delete</a>
      </div>";
    }
?>
```

Next this is my delete_modal.php

```
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog">
   <div class="modal-dialog">
     <!-- Modal content-->
     <div class="modal-content">

        <div class="modal-header">
           <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
           <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Header</h4>
        </div>

        <div class="modal-body">
          <p>Some text in the modal.</p>
        </div>

        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button  id="<?php echo $id; ?>" href="deleteposthome.php?id='.$row['post_id'].'" type="button" class="btn btn-danger" data-dismiss="modal">Delete</button>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        </div>

     </div>                                       
   </div>
</div>
```

Now this is my deleteposthome.php

```
    <?php
      require ("connection.php");  
    ?>  

    <?php
       $id =$_GET['id'];
      mysql_query("DELETE FROM posts WHERE post_id = '$id'")
      or die(mysql_error());    
    ?>
```

I don't know how to get ID so that it can be deleted using modal ! please help me

Comment: I wouldn't have the button inside the modal do the actual call for the deletion. You said that this is a confirmation modal, so what I would do is simply have a function like `deleteRow(id)` or something and call the modal from javascript, getting the yes/no confirmation, and then from there, do the magic inside that function, however you do it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to pass $\_GET variables from a link to a bootstrapmodal?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32433765/how-to-pass-get-variables-from-a-link-to-a-bootstrapmodal)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is my answer, for how many months I've asked this question.

```
<div class='modal-footer' style='background-color:#1F4E78;'>
    <a class='btn btn-danger' href='deleteposthome.php?id=".$row['post_id']."'> Delete</a>
</div>
```