# call data-target / href through script function

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrap-modal

I'm using button to call modal box of bootstrap that have dynamic value, in this way

```
<button type="button" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal_editBox" href="path/to/file.php?id=1">
```

Now I have some button that can call script function

```
action: function ( e, dt, node, config ) {
     ???
}
```

How to run my modal box in that function ?

Comment: *...run my modal...*, if you mean "show", why just not use `$('#myModal_editBox').modal('show')` from the `action` method ? By the way `href` is not a valid attribute for a `button` element.

Comment: This only show modal box without content that coming from php...

I'm using this method to load dynamic modal box

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32433765/how-to-pass-get-variables-from-a-link-to-a-bootstrapmodal/32434127#32434127

Comment: So what you want is that upon clicking the button modal should popup and also data from the href should also loaded within it. Is it so?? Are you using REST services????