# bind text to a specific id in a modalbox

Tags: php, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal

I have a while loop that echo 3 random rows from a mysql database. Each row contains of an `id` and a `description`. On my front-end each row is displayed with the id, and a very short text of the description. Each row has a button that calls a bootstrap modal box where you can read a longer description. This is how it is looking like:

[image: Modal]

My while loop that output the random id and description, and the pop up when you click the "Read More" is working fine. But in the modalbox I need to bind the description that belongs to the id (fx id:319 needs to echo testtestte in the modalbox).

I tried to follow the solution in this good explanation under the subheadline: 
[Alternate Solution with Ajax and Bootstrap Modal Event Listener](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32433765/how-to-pass-get-variables-from-a-link-to-a-bootstrapmodal) , and I got pretty far.

How can I in my file.php make a select statement that output the description, that belongs to the id of the individual button I click on?

The code that I post here is pretty long. I tried to short some down, but I think everything is relevant. If not, please give me a heads up on it.

**select_shuffle.php**

```
<!-- Everything is working in this file -->
<?php
    $sql = "SELECT id, description FROM stores ORDER BY RAND ( ) LIMIT 3";
    $res = $mysqli->query($sql);

    //print($res);
    if ($res->num_rows > 0) {
    // output data of each row
        while($row = $res->fetch_assoc()) {
            echo "id: " . $row["id"]. "<br>" .
                 "Description: " . $row["description"]. "<br><br>".
                 '<span data-placement="top" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Show"><a class="btn btn-primary btn-xs" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#editBox" data-id="<?php echo $obj->id;?>"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></span></a></span>';              
        }
    } else {
    echo "0 results";
    }
?>
<div class="modal fade" id="editBox" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                <h4 class="modal-title"><center>Heading</center></h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <div class="form-data">
                   //Here Will show the Data
                </div>

            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">Select</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Include all compiled plugins (below), or include individual files as needed -->
<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script>
$( document ).ready(function() {       
    $('#myModal').on('show.bs.modal', function (e) { //Modal Event
        var id = $(e.relatedTarget).data('id'); //Fetch id from modal trigger button
    $.ajax({
      type : 'post',
       url : 'file.php', //Here you will fetch records 
      data :  'post_id='+ id, //Pass $id
      success : function(data){
         $('.form-data').html(data);//Show fetched data from database
       }
    });
    });
});
</script>
```

The following file I do not know how to bind my selected id to the description?

**file.php**

```
<?php
include 'dbconnection.php';

if($_POST['id']) {
    $id = $_POST['id'];

    $sql = "SELECT id, description FROM stores";

    echo $sql;

     else {
    echo "0 results";
}

?>
```

Comment: Please your question is unclear. what do you want to achieve?

Comment: Thank you for the comment. I edited my question. So basically my question is: How can I in my file.php make a select statement that output the description, that belongs to the id of the individual button I click on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<button class='read-button' type='button' id="button-<?php echo $row['id'];?>">Read more</button>
```

Now when you use jQuery selector, like

`$('.read-button').click(function(){console.log($(this).attr('id');});`

will output something like *button-319*. You can set other data attribute in the button too, like `data-id=319` and use jQuery `attr()` to fetch that data. The point is you need to know which button is clicked and pass over the id.

Comment: So you want an array with key as id's and description in the values?

Comment: You should explain what you are trying to do. You click on the button and description show up in the modal box? Two ways to do it. You either get it from the description you already have in the html or do ajax call for the description by passing the id. So the question becomes how to pass the id on button click. You do that by assign id to each button.

Comment: Yes it is correct when the button that have an id of 319, I need to get that description there is in the same row. So every id has different description. Where should the jQuery selector be? In the select_shuffle.php? what about the file.php?

Comment: jQuery works on frontend. So you would have it with the other javascripts on the page.