# variabel php with mysql data in modal reveal

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

I want make link # with id to div id in one page with modal reveal

```
<a href="#?id=<?php echo $id; ?>" class="team-detail" data-reveal-id="single-news"></a>

<!-- Pop Up Windows - Single Blog Post -->
<div id="single-news" class="reveal-modal single-news small" data-reveal>

<?php
     $member = mysql_query("SELECT*FROM team WHERE id = '$_GET[id]'");
     $m = mysql_fetch_array($member);
?>  
<div class="twelve columns first-column">
    <p class="single-news-content"><?php echo $m[quote]; ?></p>
</div>
    <a class="close-reveal-modal">&#215;</a>
</div>
```

but $_GET not working, query does not work

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Change your query to this and see if it works: `$member = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM team WHERE id = " . $_GET['id'] . " ");`

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to pass the `$id` parameter in the model pop up:

Try with the below code:

```
<a class="btn btn-primary btn-xs" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#editBox" href="file.php?id=<?php echo $id;?>">
```

**Now Create a PHP file and name it file.php**

This file is called with modal call button `href="file.php?id=<?php echo $id;?"`

```
<?php
//Include database connection here
$Id = $_GET["id"]; //escape the string if you like
// Run the Query
?>
<div class="modal-header">
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
    <h4 class="modal-title"><center>Heading</center></h4>
</div>
<?php
     $member = mysql_query("SELECT*FROM team WHERE id = '$_GET[id]'");
     $m = mysql_fetch_array($member);
?>  
<div class="modal-body">
     <p class="single-news-content"><?php echo $m[quote]; ?></p>
</div>
<a class="close-reveal-modal">&#215;</a>
</div>

<script>
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $('#editBox').on('hidden.bs.modal', function () {
          $(this).removeData('bs.modal');
    });
});
</script>
```

You can see the complete process [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32433765/how-to-pass-get-variables-from-a-link-to-a-bootstrapmodal)

Hope this help!!!

Comment: but, I want in one page only, not link to other page

Comment: You need to call the second file, because if we use call aJax than we need to create the second file to fetch data. Without second file how you can pass the `$id` parameter.

Answer (score 0):

```
<a href="filename.php?id=<?php echo $id; ?>" class="team-detail" data-reveal-id="single-news"></a>
```

Pass your here

```
    <!-- Pop Up Windows - Single Blog Post -->
<div id="single-news" class="reveal-modal single-news small" data-reveal>
    <?php
        $id = $_GET['id'];
        $member = mysql_query("SELECT*FROM team WHERE id = '".$id."'");
        while($m = mysql_fetch_array($member))
        {
    ?>  
        <div class="twelve columns first-column">
            <p class="single-news-content"><?php echo $m[quote]; ?></p>
        </div>
            <a class="close-reveal-modal">&#215;</a>
        </div>
    <?php } ?>
```